# Date shifting on POST request with Angular2

Tags: oracle, angular, date

I have a problem concerning dates in my web app. I only build the front with `Angular2`, and I am using an API but I can't modify it.

My problem is the following :

I have this date in my Oracle base : `1899-12-31 20:00:00`.

I make a `GET request` and the JSON contain the following string: `"1899-12-31 20:00:00"`

With this date I make a `new Date("1899-12-31 20:00:00")` to have the following date object : `Sun Dec 31 1899 20:00:00 GMT+0100(CET)`

But now, if I make a `POST request` with this date in the body, a conversion to string is done and the date send is : `"1899-12-31T19:00:00.000Z"`

And in my base I get `1899-12-31 19:00:00`

So I lose 1 hour without modifying the data. I don't understand the conversion made by angular and how can I avoid this problem.

Comment: Is `new Date("1899-12-31 20:00:00")` being implicitly created in your time zone (CET), when it should be UTC? Can you specify the time zone it represents?

Comment: I think it could be a solution but I don't know how to do this.